# How do i get the single field value from querysnapshot in flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

actually I need to get access to the  field called userid which in my firestore collection document but I cant access it. so, please can anyone help me with this problem?the print statement only prints the data in json..

```
void logIn(String email, String password) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .where("username", isEqualTo: email)
          .where("password", isEqualTo: password)
          .get()
          .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
                if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty)
                  {
                    print(querySnapshot.docs.first.data()),

                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) =>
                              HomeScreen(userId: querySnapshot.docs.first.id),
```

this is the out put I get. but i need only the userid field:

[image]

Comment: Does `querySnapshot.docs.first.data().userId` work?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `data()` on a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html), gives you all the fields from that document. It unfortunately does so as a generic type `T?`, which is probably where you are struggling.

To get a specific field, you'll want to cast the `data()` to a `Map` and then look up that field:

```
var data = querySnapshot.docs.first.data() as Map;
var value = data["userId"];
```